# React Comment Section Character Counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey fellow developers,

so, I'm having this issue with React, and although I think I'm getting to show the 2000 as a number and a value overall, when I write inside the comment section, the number changes to NaN. I tried using the parseInt() in order to turn the span into a number, but nothing happens... Any suggestions?

Here's the code :)

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../Header";
import "./contact-form.css";

function characterCounter() {
  let text = document.getElementById("message").value;
  let textLength = text.length;
  let counter = document.getElementById("characterCounter");
  let counterNumber = parseInt(counter);
  counter.textContent = counterNumber - textLength;
}

class ContactPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <h1>Contact.</h1>
        <form action="" className="contact-form" id="contactForm">
          <label>Your Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name..." />
          <label>Your Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name..." />
          <label>Your Email</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email..." />
          <label>Your comment</label>
          <textarea
            name=""
            id="message"
            cols="10"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Hey..."
            onKeyDown={characterCounter}
          ></textarea>
          <span>
            Max words <span id="characterCounter">2000</span>
          </span>
          <button id="buttonSubmitContact" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

So... you are using React, don't you? Well I will rewrite the component to solve the issue in the React's way

```js
const MAX_CHARS = 2000
function ContactPage() {
    const [charsLeft, setCharsLeft] = useState(0);
    const updateCharsCount = ({target:{value}}) => {
        setCharsLeft(MAX_CHARS - value)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <form action="" className="contact-form" id="contactForm">
                <label>Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name..."/>
                <label>Your Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name..."/>
                <label>Your Email</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email..."/>
                <label>Your comment</label>
                <textarea
                    name=""
                    id="message"
                    cols="10"
                    rows="10"
                    placeholder="Hey..."
                    onChange={updateCharsCount}
                ></textarea>
                <span>Max words {charsLeft}/{MAX_CHARS}</span>
                <button id="buttonSubmitContact" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactPage;
```

By the way, I've used functional component instead of class component, it's the current approach